# How to pass component as props with props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react-grid library from dev-express,
There's a Table component in the library, to which we can pass Cell component,
Inside the CustomCell, i am using Menu from Material UI

```
  <Table
        columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
        cellComponent= {CustomCell}
  />
```

In the above case menu works fine,

But I want pass props to this component and i tried the following

```
 <Table
        columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
        cellComponent= {(props)=><CustomCell {...props} someFunc={this.someFunc} />}
/>
```

In this case Menu doesn't work, I wanted to know if there's an alternative way to achieve the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you surrounding Component provides the `props` you can go like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  someFunc = () => {}

  render () {
    return <Table
      columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
      cellComponent= {() => <CustomCell {...this.props} someFunc= 
        {this.someFunc} />}
      />
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `withProps`:

```
const CustomCellWithSomeFunc = withProps({someFunc: this.someFunc.bind(this)})(CustomCell);

<Table
    columnExtensions={tableColumnExtensions}
    cellComponent= {CustomCellWithSomeFunc/>}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I also want to get the props from Table Component
<CustomCell {...this.props} .. />  along with other props which i define,